# Are functions on matrices applied to the entire matrix or each row in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I've never written in Fortran, but I'm trying to adapt a script to R and the following lines are confusing me. So this is how the variable is defined:

`real, dimension(n,nd) :: x`

Does this mean `x` is `n` arrays filled with `nd` number of `real` values or a `n` x `nd` matrix?

Then

```
amax = maxval(abs(x))
x = x/amax
```

is applied. Is the variable `amax` a global max of the absolute values in `x` or is it an array of `n` max values, one for each row? This is important to know if the `x = x/amax` is being applied to each row or the entire matrix. The purpose of this function seems to be some type of normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question of the title is much more general than that of the body, so I'll come to that later.

The result of `maxval(array)` is a scalar, being the maximum value in `array` (if it's of non-zero size).

In your example, `x` is a single array of rank 2 (which is commonly thought of as being a matrix).  Thus, `maxval(x)` is indeed what you call the global maximum of that matrix.  An alternative form of `maxval` is required to give the row-by-row maxima: `maxval(x,dim=2)`.

Now, there is something else to note from your example:

```
x = x/amax
```

has a requirement about the shapes of `x` and `amax`.

You don't give a declaration for `amax` but there are two possibilities:

- `amax` has the same shape as `x`; or
- `amax` is a scalar.

[Note that `amax` needn't be a scalar just because it is assigned a scalar result from that `maxval` reference.  However, you will see that `amax` won't be declared as rank 1 with size the number of rows of `x`, so that's another clue that `maxval` is giving the global maximum.]

These two possibilities come from *conformability* rules for division.  With `amax` a scalar each element of `x` is divided by that value; with `amax` an array each element of `x` is divided by the corresponding element in `amax`.

If you want to normalize each individual row of `x` then you just can't use that division expression with `amax` a rank 1 array.

Coming to the more general question: even though it's an either/or question the answer is "no".  There is no single way.  Each function acts as it is defined.

As a general rule, though, the intrinsic functions of Fortran rarely care about the specific case of arrays which have "rows".  But one useful thought is that a function acts either:

- on all elements individually, returning an array of the same shape;
- on the array as a whole, returning a scalar.

Moderated by the fact that many will have this `dim` argument which causes the function to act on slices instead.

Comment: Fortran even has a name for those intrinsic functions which operate on array elements individually, they are called `elemental`.  The keyword `elemental` can be used on user-defined functions to tell the compiler that they can safely be applied elementally on arrays.  `maximal` is not one of those elemental functions.

Answer (score 1):

The first line means that the variable `x` is an array of two dimensions `(n,nd)` and not `n` arrays of `nd` values. The function `maxval` returns the maximum value in this array.

See page 130 (in the PDF not the printed number) in [F90_notes.pdf](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/teaching/phys660/PDF/F90_notes.pdf) (you will also find a whole chapter concerning the arrays in the same document).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Baruchel's answer: `x/amax` divides each element of the 2D array `x` by the scalar `amax`.